# I need a 32 bit version of Internet Explorer, version 7 to 9

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

My computer just updated my browser to Internet Explorer 10 64 bit. I need IE 7, 8, or 9 32 bit to run a program.

How can I get my previous version of Internet Explorer back?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to uninstall IE10, IE10 still has an 32-bit version within your pc it is usually located at.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer

Get a program like [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check the program is running in 32 bit.

[image]

**Edit**: I know that the poster needs an older IE, however if the issue can be solved with 32 bit IE with comparability mode I don't see the need to downgrade IE. This is how I run it in compatability mode.

**[Source](http://techathlon.com/internet-explorer-10-run-compatibility-mode/)**

1. Open up Internet Explorer 10.
2. Press ‘Alt’ key on your keyboard to bring up the top menu. And then go to Tools > Developer Tools. Alternatively you can just press the ‘F12’ key on your keyboard.

[image]

Go to Tools > Developer Tools

3. This will bring up the IE developer tools which looks just like the one in Google Chrome at the bottom.

[image]

You can then click ‘Browser Mode’ and then click on the Internet Explorer version you want to simulate. You can also set the document mode to quirks mode or standards mod from the next drop down .

Comment: If you're going to down vote this answer please explain why.

Comment: He specifically mentions needing an earlier version of IE: "I need IE 7, 8, or 9 32 bit"

Comment: @Davidw Ok I've edited my answer, hope that it doesn't cause any confusion if it still doesn't seem to help I'll remove it :) .

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall IE10 by going to Start, Control Panel, Programs and Features, (It would be under Programs in Category view), Installed Updates (in the upper right corner), find IE 10, and click on Uninstall, at the left top of the list of installed updates.

Comment: This is why I suggested uninstalling IE 10: "I need IE 7, 8, or 9 32 bit" I believe IE 7 or 8 comes with Windows 7. It won't remove IE completely, just the update to 10.